# JSON return unreadable data; how do I get the proper objects? (Kotlin, Android Studio)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I have `JSON` that looks like this:

```
[{"name":"John","age":30,"vehicle":"bicycle"},
{"name":"Bob","age":32,"vehicle":"walking"}]
```

The `interface`

```
@GET("lnjb8")
fun findPosts(): Call<List<RetrofitVariables>>
```

The variables for deserialisation:

```
class RetrofitVariables(name: String, age: String, vehicle: String) {}
```

And in the `MainActivity()`:

```
val myRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

    val repository = myRetrofit.create(RetrofitCalls::class.java)

    val call = repository.findPosts()
```

...followed by the asynchronous call:

```
call.enqueue(object: Callback<List<RetrofitVariables>> {
    override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<RetrofitVariables>>?, response: Response<List<RetrofitVariables>>?) {

        val jsonVariables = response!!.body()

        //THIS SHOULD PRODUCE THE PROPER DATA
        jsonVariables!!.forEach { println("TAG testing" + it) }
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<RetrofitVariables>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            println("TAG FAIL")
        }
    })
```

`jsonVariables!!.forEach { println("TAG testing" + it) }` should give me the data, but instead it just gives `testingcom.slothmode.retrofitexercise.RetrofitVariables@83098f7` Obviously, it collects the data since it gets a response, but I must have missed how to display it properly. In previous projects I have used `value` as in x.value.toString() but I don't see how that apply here.

How do I display the proper data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being shown that way because you haven't implemented `toString()` method. You can either implement `toString()` in `RetrofitVariables` class or you can declare `RetrofitVariables` as `data class` and have it implemented by the compiler.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! I made `RetrofitVariables` into a `data class` declared with `val` and it worked like a charm: `data class RetrofitVariables(val name: String, val age: Int, val vehicle: String) {}` Thanks a lot for your help @Maroš Šeleng !

Comment: Glad to help. BTW, what you got printed is the class name and instance's hashcode, should you be curious :)

Comment: Ah, I figured it was something like that :) Again, thanks for taking the time, really! :)